# using CodePush without ejecting from expo

Tags: react-native, expo, code-push, react-native-code-push

I am interest in using codepush with expo instead of expo-updates. The reason is that I find expo-updates to be overpriced.

Is it possible to use CodePush **without ejecting from expo**? I would like to get some guidance on how to do this.